# Why is my code printing the wrong ciphertext?

Tags: c++, encryption, codeblocks

I am trying to make a program that turns a string into encryption by going ten letters ahead of each letter. https://gyazo.com/86f9d708c2f02cf2d70dbc1cd9fa9a06 I am doing part 2. When I input "helloworld" something like 0x45 something comes up. Please help! This is due soon!

I am tried messing around with the for loops but it didn't help.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Input Message
    cout << "Enter a message" << endl;
    string message;
    getline(cin, message);

    //Convert Message to Numbers
    int numMess[message.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i<message.length(); i++) {
        numMess[i] = (int)message[i];
    }

    cout << numMess << endl;

    //Encrypt Number Message by adding ten to each one
    int encryptNumMess[message.length()];
    for (int a = 0; a < message.length(); a++){
        encryptNumMess[a] = numMess[a] + 10;
        if (encryptNumMess[a] > 122) {
            encryptNumMess[a] = 97;
        }
    }
    cout << encryptNumMess << endl;

    //Convert Encrypted Number Message to letters
    string encryption[message.length()];
    for (int b = 0; b<message.length(); b++) {
        encryption[b] = (char)encryptNumMess[b];
    }

    cout << encryption << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I expect when I type "helloworld" the final product will be "rovvygybvn"

Comment: `int numMess[message.length()];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have the number of entries denoted by a compile-time constant, not a runtime value.  Just use  `std::vector<int>` instead.

Comment: Consider that, with your current code, any number after "encryption" that is larger than 122 will become A.  Does that sound correct to you...?

Comment: `string encryption[message.length()];` this doesn't do what you seemingly expect it to do.

Comment: @n.m.  It doesn't do anything with my compiler except emit an error :)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i replaced it but it didn't work.

Comment: "Didn't work" is a very poor problem statement.  Help us to help you.

Comment: Also, don't use numbers such as 122, 97, etc.  Use the actual characters themselves, i.e. 'a', 'b', etc.  Better yet, just create a constant string, `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` and work with that.  Then the program becomes independent of the character encoding and/or collating sequence.

Comment: `cout << encryptNumMess << endl;` makes no sense; you can't print an array of `int` that way. And why are you trying to use an array of `string` for the ciphertext? (Yes, "ciphertext" is what it's called.)  You must *go back and work on simpler exercises* until these points become clear.

Comment: BTW, the way you solve this is to use the modulus operator `%`  to accomplish "adding 10" in a wheel-like fashion.  I think you need to use pencil and paper to see how to get the character when 10 is added to it.

Comment: Can someone please write an answer? I am so new to this so I can barely understand.

Comment: @JohnBob -- Sure an answer can be written.  The problem is that you don't learn anything from it, especially if someone were to post the professional way of doing this using STL algorithm functions instead of hand-rolled loops.  How would you explain that to your teacher when he or she asks you to explain?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I usually read over the code and teach myself how it makes sense.

Comment: Two things: Don't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If by e.g. `97` you mean the (technically non-portable) ASCII code for `'a'` then *say* `'a'`. And if you use C-style casting (like e.g. `(int)message[i]`) then you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to scrap the hand-coded loops, you can use the STL algorithms such as [std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) to accomplish this:

But first, there are a few things you should do:

Don't use magic numbers such as 122, 97, etc.  Instead use the actual character constants, i.e `a`, `b`, etc.  However if we assume ASCII, where the alphabetic character codes are contiguous, your particular program could simply use a constant string to denote the alphabet, and then use simple indexing to pick out the character.

```
const char *alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

Then to get the letter `a`, a simple subtraction is all that's required to get the index:

```
char ch = 'b';
int index = ch - 'a'; // same as 'b' - 'a' == 98 - 97 == 1
std::cout << alphabet[index]; // will print 'b'
```

Given this, the next thing is to figure out what character is reached if you add 10 to the value, and if greater than 26, wrap around to the beginning of the alphabet.  This can be done using modulus (remainder after division)

```
char ch = 'x';
int index = (ch - 'a' + 10) % 26; // Same as ('x' - 'a' + 10) % 26 == (120 - 97 + 10) % 26  == 33 % 26 == 7
std::cout << alphabet[index]; // will print 'h'
```

The next thing is to figure out the opposite, where given an encrypted character, you have to find the unencrypted character by subtracting 10.  Here this wraps the opposite way, so a little more work needs to be done (not shown, but code sample reflects what is done).

Putting this all together, and using `std::transform` and lambdas, we get the following small program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    //Input Message
    const char *alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    std::string message = "helloworld";
    std::string result;

    // set the encrypted string using the formula above and std::transform
    std::transform(message.begin(), message.end(), std::back_inserter(result),
                  [&](char ch) { return alphabet[(ch - 'a' + 10) % 26]; });
    std::cout << "Encrypted: " << result << '\n';  

    // convert back to unencrypted using the above formula and std::transform
    std::string result2;
    std::transform(result.begin(), result.end(), std::back_inserter(result2),
                  [&](char ch) 
                  { int index = ch - 'a' - 10;  index = index < 0?26 - (abs(index) % 26):index % 26; return alphabet[index];});
    std::cout << "Unencrypted: " << result2;                  
}
```

Output:

```
 Encrypted: rovvygybvn
 Unencrypted: helloworld
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works for encrypt, if you want to decrypt you should chande `newAlphabet` and `oldAlphabet`

I comment in the code that which `newAlphabet` and `oldAlphabet` are for encrypt and which are for decrypt

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // For Encrypt
    string newAlphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string oldAlphabet = "klmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghij";

    // For Decrypt
    //string newAlphabet = "klmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghij";
    //string oldAlphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";


    string input = "";
    string output = "";

    getline(cin, input);
    int inputLen = input.size();

    if (oldAlphabet.size() != newAlphabet.size())
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < inputLen; ++i)
    {
        int oldCharIndex = oldAlphabet.find(tolower(input[i]));

        if (oldCharIndex >= 0)
            output += isupper(input[i]) ? toupper(newAlphabet[oldCharIndex]) : newAlphabet[oldCharIndex];
        else
            output += input[i];
    }
    cout << output << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned `int numMess[message.length()];` is not valid c++.
If it works for you, you're using compiler extension which you really shouldn't rely on. The correct way would be:

```cpp
std::vector <int> numMess(message.length());
```

Look up the [std::vector reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for more info.

Next, `int encryptNumMess[100];` creates a C array style array. `encryptNumMess` is the base pointer to the array. when you try `std::cout << encryptNumMess` it'll output the pointer value, NOT the array. You'll need a for loop for doing that, like so :

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    std::cout << encryptNumMess[i] << " ";
std::cout << endl;
```

The above also works when you convert this to a vector like we did with numMess whereas in that case, `std::cout << encryptNumMess` wouldn't even compile.

Thirdly, `string encryption[100]` creates an array of 100 strings! Not a string of size 100. To do that:

```cpp
std::string foo(message.length(), '\0');
```

We have to specify what character to fill the string with. Thus us `'\0'`.
And now, for the string, to output it, you may use `std::cout << foo`.

Lastly, since arithmetic is allowed on `char`, the entire program may be shortened to just this

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // Input Message
    std::cout << "Enter a message" << std::endl;
    std::string message, encryption;
    getline(std::cin, message);

    // Resize encryption string to the desired length
    encryption.resize(message.length());

    // Do the encryption
    for(size_t i = 0; i < message.length(); ++i) {
        encryption[i] = message[i] + 10;
        if (encryption[i] > 122) {
            encryption[i] = 97;
        }
    }

    // Output the string
    std::cout << encryption << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, your encryption algorithm is still not correct as per instructions, but I'll leave that for you to figure out. I believe @PaulMcKenzie has already told you most of how to fix it, and also to not use magic numbers.